# Use ffmpeg to convert .mkv to .mp4 while retaining hard-embedded subs

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion, subtitles

I'm trying to convert an mkv video into mp4 while keeping the hard-embedded subs. Extra information is below - does anyone know which command I should use to make this work?

So far I've tried these commands which have successfully converted to mp4 but lost the subs:

- `ffmpeg -i <input-mkv> -c:a copy -c:s mov_text <output-mp4>`
- `ffmpeg -i <input-mkv> -c copy -c:s mov_text <output-mp4>`
- `ffmpeg -i <input-mkv> -c:a copy -c:s mov_text -x265-params crf=25 <output-mp4>`

ffprobe:

```
$ ffprobe -i "[ENG SUB] 210313 IZ*ONE [ONE, THE STORY] - Day 1.mkv"
ffprobe version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3.1_4 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '[ENG SUB] 210313 IZ*ONE [ONE, THE STORY] - Day 1.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libebml v1.4.1 + libmatroska v1.6.2
    creation_time   : 2021-03-15T04:54:47.000000Z
  Duration: 04:05:30.73, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6177 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 5860392
      DURATION-eng    : 04:05:30.716000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 441480
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 10790971990
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v53.0.0 ('Fool's Gold') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2021-03-15 04:54:47
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 314047
      DURATION-eng    : 04:05:30.709000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 690502
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 578268363
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v53.0.0 ('Fool's Gold') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2021-03-15 04:54:47
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: ass (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 132
      DURATION-eng    : 03:04:16.610000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 2525
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 183731
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v53.0.0 ('Fool's Gold') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2021-03-15 04:54:47
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:3(jpn): Subtitle: ass
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 235
      DURATION-eng    : 03:04:33.060000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 3386
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 325684
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v53.0.0 ('Fool's Gold') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2021-03-15 04:54:47
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:4(chi): Subtitle: ass
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 131
      DURATION-eng    : 03:04:21.120000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 3048
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 181298
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v53.0.0 ('Fool's Gold') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2021-03-15 04:54:47
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
```

Answer (score 1):

Your output shows:

> Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: ass (default)

However, mp4 does not support `ass`. You'd need to extract the `ass`, turn it in to something that `mp4` supports, and then mix the two. `ffmpeg -i <input.mkv> -vf subtitles=<input.mkv> <output.mp4>` is one approach. Alternatively, I hear good things about a tool called [Handbreak](https://handbrake.fr/).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! When trying this out, I get this error:
```
[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x7f93e7205680] No filename provided!
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7f93e2806800] Error initializing filter 'subtitles' with args ''
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
[aac @ 0x7f93e480e600] Qavg: 65536.000
[aac @ 0x7f93e480e600] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
Conversion failed!
```